# HTML radio button is not selected using jQuery/Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a popbox box with HTML form which is showing all user information to appropriate HTML filed from db based on id using jQuery/Ajax.

Now all form field is fill up but radio button is not **selected**. It should be selected based on a condition like..if **kittype == 1** then select first one otherwise second one.

```
<td>Kittype</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="kittype" value="1"/> &nbsp; Electronic Kit Only <br/>
<input type="radio" name="kittype" value="2" /> &nbsp; Post a Hard Copy as 
well<br/>   
</td>
```

**Jquery/Ajax Code:**

```
function myfunc1(id) {
        id = id;
        $.ajax({        
                url: 'edit_user_details.php',
                type: 'post',             
                data: {'id' : id},
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function( res ) {
                    console.log(res);
                    $.each( res, function( key, value ) {
                        console.log(key, value);
                        $('input[type=text][name='+key+']').val(value);
                        $('textarea[name='+key+']').val(value);

                        if ( res.kittype == 1 ) {
                            $('input[type=radio][name='+kittype+']').attr('checked', 'checked');

                        }

                    });




                }            
        });
    }
```

Comment: try use `Prop()` http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe `prop()` instead of `attr()`.

Also you can use `:first` or `eq(0)` for getting the first element.

```
if (res.kittype == 1) {
    $('input[type=radio][name=kittype]:first').prop('checked', 'checked');
    $("input").is(':checked');
} else {
    $('input[type=radio][name=kittype]:not(:first)').prop('checked', 'checked');

}
```

Comment: But Second one is not selected is kittype =2 and information from db is not showing also !

Comment: @Babu you may refer to my simple answer if the db can return either kittype=1 or 2.

Comment: ohh sorry can you pls check now?

Comment: @Babu $('input[type=radio][name=kittype]:not(:first)').

Comment: No, It's not selected if kittype = 2. Now information is showing but second one is not selected if I change kittype =  2 from db.

Comment: In this fiddle it's selected but why it's not selected based on condition ? It's only select first one.

Comment: i think you res.kittype is always returning 1

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I'm checking it again. please wait.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52491/discussion-between-babu-and-anoop-joshi)

Answer (score 0):

Use prop method of jquery.

```
$('input[type=radio][name='+kittype+']').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes as

```
$('input[type=radio][name="kittype"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/49xJC/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply write

```
$('input[type=radio][name=kittype][value='+res.kittype+']').prop('checked', 'checked');
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hQYdZ/)